# AngularJs one controller for multiple DOM/scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-scope

Maybe tricky title...

For example lets use Google Maps Api v3.

I have array of JSON objects with coordinates and information for various cities.
What if i want to create ONE controller for all InfoWindow content (the logic of each content is the same, but only data differs).

The main point: in each InfoWindow i want to "communicate" with information about each location. So i whant to have one Controller and build multiple $scope instances.

I can bind controller into InfoWindow content loading template there through parent Controller:

```
$con = $compile(HTML)($scope);
```

Then pushing $con[0] as content into InfoBox(or Window) content.
where HTML can be for example:

```
<div ng-controller="CustomCtrl">
    {{city().name}}
</div>
```

The problem is how can i push custom variable/object to CustomCtrl?
That variable can be any. In architecture logic structure will be the same, but technically that must be various objects.

I tried to do so:

```
var content = $con[0].copyNode(false); // or true
content.customVariable = <Anything here>;
var infobox = new InfoBox({content: content,...});
```

And i have nothing by accessing in "CustomCtrl" by $element[0].customVariable.

How i solve this problem in AngularJS?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I figured that out by me own.

The first thing that must be done for my task is that i must $compile each time for each marker,
after that when i initialized InfoBox(-Window doesn`t matter) i get that content instance.

And then i can know for sure that InfoBox content as **html content, as DOM element, must be with unique instance, not the same one**:

```
var elem = angular.element(city.infobox.getContent());
elem.scope().customVariable = <Anything here>
```

This customVariable will be accessible then in "CustomCtrl" code ;)

It is like as to bind to each ng-repeat "item in items" a controller:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-controller="ItemCtrl">
    {{item.name}}
</li>
```

Each  will be as separate $scope in ItemCtrl closure, and `item` can be accesable there:

```
$scope.item.any_param_or_fn();
```

But in my example i created manually all items, so i must to do that data binding manually.